# Solving page reload in HTML5 histroy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my code , iam using Html 5 history and its work fine in getting contents and changing url but when i refresh the page its show only the content without full page with css and here my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            $('.menuAnchor').click(function(e) {                
                href = $(this).attr("href");                
                loadContent(href);                  
                // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
                history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);
                e.preventDefault();                                 
            });

            // THIS EVENT MAKES SURE THAT THE BACK/FORWARD BUTTONS WORK AS WELL
            window.onpopstate = function(event) {                   
                console.log("pathname: "+location.pathname);
                loadContent(location.pathname);
            };    
        });

        function loadContent(url){
            // USES JQUERY TO LOAD THE CONTENT
             $.get(url, {}, function (data) {
                $(".contn_btm_mid_bg").html(data);
                //$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(".contn_btm_mid_bg");
            });

            // THESE TWO LINES JUST MAKE SURE THAT THE NAV BAR REFLECTS THE CURRENT URL
            $('li').removeClass('current');
            $('a[href="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass('current');                
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Are you including your CSS in the ajax call? or how is your css loaded?

Comment: i call the ajax in index page which include a menu and as click in a link from menu it opened in a div in the same page and the url change its state to the page called

Comment: Can you show the contents of your index page?

Comment: first calling external css files  then scripts then included the leftside bar which contain links and i put a div that pushing the other pages in it but the other pages only contains divs and contents no css in it when i call it it looks fine

Comment: These "other" pages you are referring to, are they just references in the same doc or actual different html files? If they are different html files you need link to your CSS in those files too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) to change my URL using ajax and it works fine for me. Your `CSS` shouldn't really change if you have it linked in your document. Are you overwriting it?
Declare your `CSS` in the head of the page that you're doing the ajax call on and on ajax load only update the `DIV` or whatever element with the contents of the ajax call. I do that with this plugin and it works great for me. My `CSS` is always there even on page refresh.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" linktoyourfile.css" media="screen"> 
<!--js files etc -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="contn_btm_mid_bg"><!--ajax contents--></div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Since I can't see your HTML or structure I will just tell you how I might do it based on your comment.

Don't call the whole page. Just call the div that contains the content you want to import via ajax. Not the whole page. Link the CSS on all your included pages in the header. Then use a DIV to hold the content, when you call that page, just call the id of the DIV not the entire page. example

Your other pages:

Then in your ajax call if your divs have the same class in all the pages you can do this below. Make sure you link your CSS in your other pages too.

```
 function loadContent(url){
            // USES JQUERY TO LOAD THE CONTENT
             $.get(url, {}, function (data) {
                $(".contn_btm_mid_bg").html($(data).find('.contn_btm_mid_bg').html());
                //$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(".contn_btm_mid_bg");
            });

            // THESE TWO LINES JUST MAKE SURE THAT THE NAV BAR REFLECTS THE CURRENT URL
            $('li').removeClass('current');
            $('a[href="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass('current');                
        }
```

Comment: my page really the same logic as you mention and inside the <div class="contn_btm_mid_bg"> i openned the other page using Html5 history  and the script work fine in getting contents from pages and the state backward and forward also work fine but when i refresh the page it show the content page .

Comment: The other pages that you load need to have a reference to the CSS in those pages as well. When you call the ajax into a page that has a reference to the CSS it will show up correctly. But if you refresh on the page that was pulled in by ajax it won't have CSS defined. Try putting a link to the CSS file in your other pages and see what happens.

Comment: right , and fine iam sure that the css will work but the other included pages which they are  the header page and the leftside_bar page, if i included them in the called page they will appear with the content .

Comment: the main idea from all of that i want the page to reload in the same state as it looks , the header page and the leftside bar page and the current content in  page and footer will be the same , and not to show  the content only without other included pages

Comment: my friend as you know that when we call a page the url will change its state from case to another for example: mydomain/index.php  this is the main page,  Ive called page contactus.php which include form with css and code to save to database and not include header page and leftside bar page. The state of url will change to mydomain/contactus.php , remeber i called it inside index.php and it appear very well, but when i reload the the url : mydomain/contactus.php it show the form elements and the head and leftsidebar menu not appear .

Comment: Ok, what happens when you load mydomain/contactus.php directly. Don't call it with ajax. Type that into your browser address bar and load that page. Does it show with the CSS or not?

Comment: it show only the form elements with css but the header page and leftsidebar page not appear beacause I was not included them in contactus page, I cant included them since they will appear with the form , but i think my script code must include a code  to show the same state that page look before reload.

Comment: On my site, all my pages work. So if I load it directly it will show correctly, if I load via ajax using history.js it will still work. e.g. my contact us page is loaded with full html, css and elements. If I call it via ajax on the menu, I ONLY change the contents of the page im on by calling the DIV that contains my forms on the contact us page. I gave you an example of how do that. Your page has to show correctly because if the user just types that in it will not come up with the form. All pages must work without ajax first, then use ajax for navigation like the example I gave.

Comment: thats good my friend , i think that is your answer now is clear, thanks for your patience and thanks for your support at all , your answers at all was helpful , i wish to you a nice day and good luck in your working life and in all your life domains.